# Elixir Phoenix Page Reloads After Image Uploads

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Working on one of my first Phoenix projects. As part of it, I've created a drag and drop file upload for a markdown text edit field (similar to SO/GitHub.) When a file is dropped into the field, I am hitting an async controller action to save the file to the filesystem.

Here's the controller action that handles the async file upload:

```
def create_photo(conn, %{"images" => upload}) do
  if uploaded_file = upload do
    File.cp(uploaded_file.path, Application.app_dir(:my_app, "/priv/static/images/#{uploaded_file.filename}"))
  end
  render(conn, "upload.json", path: "/images/#{uploaded_file.filename}")
end
```

I have been stuck trying to figure out why the page reloads when this action fires off. I thought it was something client side that I was doing wrong, but I just figured out that the page refreshes each time because of the hot reloading feature:

```
# Watch static and templates for browser reloading.
config :my_app, MayApp.Endpoint,
  live_reload: [
    patterns: [
      ~r{priv/static/.*(js|css|png|jpeg|jpg|gif|svg)$},
      ...
```

Because the app is configured to reload when `priv/static/images` changes, it gives the illusion that a form is submitted and the page is refreshed when I upload a file.

Have I chosen a bad place to store uploaded files? I chose this static path because I can reference images in the markdown text field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right on point with your last assumption. priv/static is for assets that don't change, hence the name.

I suggest you move the file to /uploads/images then add the following to your endpoint, in order for Phoenix to serve them.

`plug Plug.Static, at: "/uploads", from: Path.expand('./uploads'), gzip:
 (Mix.env == :prod)`

But then again, you could always just remove the image formats from your upload, if you insist on using the /priv dir.

```
# Watch static and templates for browser reloading.
config :my_app, MayApp.Endpoint,
  live_reload: [
    patterns: [
      ~r{priv/static/.*(js|css|svg)$},
```

Comment: I like your suggestion, that's what I'm thinking I will do. You can have more than one `Plug.Static` plugs I assume? I want to keep the existing one as well.

Comment: You sure can :-)